# Flutter textFormField inputFormatter for the input

Tags: flutter, dart

I m a newbie to the flutter and need your help in setting the inputFormatters for the input like "AB-2121-11-2121" or "AB-2121-11-21214"
First two characters should be like below
two characters - 4 digits - 2 digits - 4/5 digits

Need your help in getting the formatter

Thanks
Ganeshc

Comment: Have you considered using regex pattern ? something like ` r'^([A-Za-z]{2})-(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{4,5})$';`

Comment: Can you share the full program ?

Answer (score 2):

To achieve this, define a regular expression pattern that matches the desired pattern like the RegExp class below

```
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
     TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
   final RegExp regExp = RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4,5}$');
```

This pattern matches two alphabetical characters (uppercase or lowercase) followed by a hyphen, four digits, another hyphen, two digits, and finally either four or five digits. This is the pattern you described in your  question.

Comment: Can you share the the complete program to try out ? Your help is deeply appreciated . Thanks

Comment: Hi, 
This code will work if i enter input AS-2211-11-2121 at once in a TextFormField . But i need to take care of this condition for every character input .
                              TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                                    (TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
                                   
                                  return RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4,5}$').hasMatch(newValue.text) ? newValue : oldValue;
                                },
                              ).

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to resolve the issue. Yeah this is not a feasible/proper but it works for me .

```
                      TextFormField(
                        controller: _serialNumber,
                        autofillHints: [AutofillHints.name],
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: 'serialNumber',
                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                              color: Colors.greenAccent,),
                          ),
                          border: OutlineInputBorder(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20.0),
                          ),
                        ),
                        inputFormatters: [
                          //SNInputFormatters.SNInputFilter(),
                          LengthLimitingTextInputFormatter(18),
                          SNInputFormatter(),
                          // TextInputFormatter.withFunction(
                          //       (TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
                          //         print('oldValue ${oldValue.text} newValue ${newValue.text}');
                          //     return RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z]{2}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{4,5}$').hasMatch(newValue.text) ? newValue : oldValue;
                          //   },
                          // ),
                        ],
                        validator: (value)  {
                          if (value!.isEmpty) {
                            return 'This field is required';
                          }
                        },
                      )
```

class SNInputFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {

@override
TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
var text = newValue.text;

```
if (newValue.selection.baseOffset == 0) {
  return newValue;
}

int dotCounter = 0;
var buffer = StringBuffer();
String snField = "";

print("text.length ${text.length}");
for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
  print('text[i] ${text[i]}');

  if((i==0) && RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z]$').hasMatch(text[0])){
    print('buffer text[i] ${text[i]}');
    buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
  if((i==1) && RegExp(r'^[A-Za-z]$').hasMatch(text[1])){
    print('buffer text[i] ${text[i]}');
    buffer.write(text[i]);
    buffer.write("-");
  }
  if(((i==3) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[3])) ||
      ((i==4) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[4])) ||
      ((i==5) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[5])) ||
      ((i==6) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[6]))){
        print('buffer text[$i] ${text[i]}');
        buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
  if(i==6){
    buffer.write("-");
  }
  if(((i==8) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[8])) ||
      ((i==9) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[9]))){
    print('buffer text[i] ${text[i]}');
    buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
  if(i==9){
    buffer.write("-");
  }
  if(((i==11) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[11])) ||
      ((i==12) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[12])) ||
      ((i==13) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[13])) ||
      ((i==14) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[14])) ||
      ((i==15) && RegExp(r'^[0-9]$').hasMatch(text[15]))){
    print('buffer text[i] ${text[i]}');
    buffer.write(text[i]);
  }
}

var string = buffer.toString();
return newValue.copyWith(
    text: string,
    selection: TextSelection.collapsed(offset: string.length));
```

}
}